# can't write cookie in asmx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, cookies, asmx

i am trying to create a cookie in a web service when testing this code it works  when i call it from aspx page it return "Done" but the cookie is not created

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string CreateCookie()
    {

        var Cookies = new HttpCookie("test123");
        Cookies.Value = "123";
        Cookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(Cookies);
        return "Done";
    }
```

My Request

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/testservice.asmx/CreateCookie");
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentLength = 0;


        HttpWebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: I believe your webmethod lives inside a different virtual directory and as such the HttpContext will be different. What is your reasoning for wanting to create a cookie via webservice?

Comment: the Reason is to give temporary access to users

Comment: What I mean is, why can't your application(s) create the cookies?